# MapQuest Search API not yielding proper result

Tags: mapquest

I have some data in MapQuest Data Manager v2 (DMv2) and I am trying to search this hosted data set using their search API(Web Service) but I am not getting desired results. Following are the snapshot of my data set and queries I am using :

These are the fields :

```
"storeid","brandname","onlineorderingenabled","street","zipcode","state","geocodereturncode","city","country","mqap_geography","mqap_quality","landmark","county","mqap_id","storename","longitude","latitude"
```

and this is sample row :

```
"1","Chili's","true","12815 Preston Rd","75230-1302","TX","","Dallas","US","POINT (-96.80363 32.92329)","P1AAA","","Dallas","ca6b6bae-945f-45fc-a8d1-3d512796150d","Preston/LBJ-Chili's","",""
```

Sample search queries :

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/search?key=[My_Key here]&shapePoints=-80,26&outFormat=json&hostedData=hostedData=mqap.121144_BrinkerStores|storename ILIKE ?|Preston/LBJ-Chili's|storeid,storename,city


http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=[My_Key]&origin=Dallas&inFormat=json&json={hostedData:[{tableName:mqap.121144_BrinkerStores,extraCriteria:City ILIKE ?,parameters:[Dallas],columnNames:[storeid,storename,city,state]}]}
```

I am not getting `storedid,storenam,city,state`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the search/v2/search request, make sure your shapePoints are latititude,longitude and not the other way around.  And the apostrophe in the storename needs to be double apostrophe'd for the postgres backend.

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/search?key=KEY&shapePoints=32.778149,-96.795403&hostedData=mqap.121144_BrinkerStores|storename=?|Knox-Chili%27%27s
```

In the search/v2/radius request, include the origin in the json and rename hostedData to hostedDataList.

```
www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=KEY&inFormat=json&json={"origin":"Dallas,TX","hostedDataList":[{"tableName":"mqap.121144_BrinkerStores","extraCriteria":"City ILIKE ?","parameters":["Dallas"],columnNames:["storeid","storename","city","state"]}]}
```